# Can you mine Monero using sgminer?

Tags: cgminer, miner-configuration, guiminer, monero

I've been mining Monero using my sgminer. I pointed it at https://moneropool.com/, but i when i visit the site to see my stats i see that my address is not found. Is my miner not working?

Comment: Are you aware that Monero uses CryptoNote as their hashing algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. Monero uses a different PoW that is incompatible with sgminer, but also uses a different pool communication protocol that is Stratum-like but not actually Stratum.